# .htaccess multiple rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Use the following rule if you want to make the page like a directory
RewriteRule ^(v)$ /$1/
# The following rule does the rewrite.
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ profile.php?name=$1
# The following rewrite the other way round:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/profile.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD|TRACE)\ /profile.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^profile.php$ %1?
```

I'm doing this code above in my .htaccess file, this works fine in my profile.php page because before, my profile.php is displaying this kind of URL:

```
http://mysite.com/profile.php?name=john
```

but when I wrote that code this is the result:

```
http://mysite.com/john/
```

I also wanted to apply this code to my category.php, so what I did was just to copy the code above and my whole .htaccess file looks like this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Use the following rule if you want to make the page like a directory
RewriteRule ^(v)$ /$1/

# The following rule does the rewrite.
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ profile.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ category.php?cid=$1

# The following rewrite the other way round:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/profile.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD|TRACE)\ /profile.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^profile.php$ %1?

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/category.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD|TRACE)\ /category.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cid=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^category.php$ %1?
```

But this code gives me a weird result because when I visit 
`http://mysite.com/john/` the content that i'm seeing is the content of my category.php.

What should I do here? Any help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Thanks!

Comment: How is the system supposed to know what is a name and what is a category? You need to define that first.

Comment: @jeroen The url of my category is like this:
http://mysite.com/category.php?id=1 while my profile it was like this: http://mysite.com/profile.php?id=1

Comment: Yes, but your rewritten urls would be for example `mysite.com/john/` and `mysite.com/movies/`. What defines a category in the new url and what a name?

Comment: they are different by actual URL but on the rewrite version they are the same so the server can't differentiate if `/john` is supposed to be profile or category.

Comment: I see, I got your point, so I shuld change it to something like mysite.com/user/john/ while the other is mysite.com/category/movies/

Comment: That's why my answer on your previous question starts with `u/`

Answer (score 1):

i have got the problem in ur rule. the problem what i suppose is that your webserver is unable to differentiate the request is of category page / profile page whenever an request comes like
http://mysite.com/john/

so i suggest do one change in either profile page request or in category page request.

simply add http://mysite.com/profile/john/

hope this works out.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question as it was modified in the comments:

To differentiate between users and categories if these terms appear in the url, you only need one line per rule (untested example):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)/?$ /profile.php?name=$1    // using only a limited set of chars (letters and underscore) for the user name and an optional / at the end

RewriteRule ^category/(\w+)/?$ /category.php?cid=$1    // using only a limited set of chars for the category (letters and underscore) and an optional / at the end
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I also made my own answer below. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I solved it using this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Use the following rule if you want to make the page like a directory
RewriteRule ^user/(!(profile.php))$ user/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/(!(category.php))$ category/$1/ [R=301,L]

# The following rule does the rewrite.
RewriteRule ^user/(.+)/$ profile.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)/$ category.php?id=$1

# The following rewrite the other way round:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/profile.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD|TRACE)\ /profile.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^profile.php$ user/%1?

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/category.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD|TRACE)\ /category.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^category.php$ category/%1?
```

Comment: But wen I used this code and I type in http://mysite.com/user/john (without slash in the last character) it returns a 404 error, but if there is it returns perfectly. What do you think is happening here?